# How to detect when the scrollbar has reached the top or bottom of webpage?

Tags: android, webview

I am working with `WebView` and my problem is that whenever the scrollbar reaches to the end or top of `WebView` it should indicate this to me with some boolean value so that I can display the next and previous page correspondingly.

I am working on a project and I want to show a HTML file as a html reader so I want to know whenever the scrollbar reaches the end of webpage so I can load the further pages.

Comment: You should read the FAQ about how to write questions in here :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make note of the improvements to the formatting in your post; you can see the Markdown Syntax used to format the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c52ad3af-9600-419f-9bfd-7b6ef10af9ad/view-source). Formatting help can also be found http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/.

Answer (score 4):

I do recommend you iScroll:

`http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4`

It's easy to use and it works fairly perfect on every mobile platforms.

Comment: thanks but i am working on android platform and sorry i did not get your answer exactly,please explain me??

Comment: iscroll, it is a JavaScript lib, to handle your problem. you'd better read the introduction about iscroll